# CSS not loading when using AJAX in IE

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to load a php file using ajax and all is working perfectly in chrome.
but when using IE, the CSS in the php file is not working.

here are my codes for the AJAX:

```
function showUser() {
   var skill = document.getElementById("skill").value
   if ( skill == "" ) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      return;
   }
   if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + skill, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

getuser.php has css codes that works and echos `<img src = 'pics.jpg' class ='img_div'>`
so again, it works with chrome but the css did not apply in IE.

Thanks,
James

Comment: What is the css that is not loaded in IE

Comment: just a simple css to change width, height of the pictures. the getuser.php returns a table with pictures inside.

Comment: Post getuser.php's output please.